# ModalViewController to retain value

Tags: iphone, ios5

From the modalViewController (UniversitiesViewController *), I've tried to set a variable in the rootViewController with no luck.  In my tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method I use the following code to set the rootViewController (MapsViewController *) selectedIndex property:

```
MapsViewController *mapsView = (MapsViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapsView"];
mapsView.selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When I print the value of self.selectedIndex in the MapViewController it is always 0, which is not the value selected.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hampus has the right answer, but I think you're also just creating a new MapsViewController and setting a value on it. You never actually do anything with the mapsView, and it will go out of scope at the end of the method. If your parent was a MapsViewController, this wouldn't get you that particular instance anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create a delegate protocol for the UniversitiesViewController.

```
@protocol UniversitiesViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)universitiesViewController:(UniversitiesViewController *)uvc selectedIndex:(NSInteger)index;
@end
```

And add

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UniversitiesViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

to the UniversitiesViewController class.

In didSelectRow in the UniversitiesViewController, call

```
[self.delegate universitiesViewController:self selectedIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Then from MapsViewController, when instantiating UniversitiesViewController (or if using segues, in prepareForSegue) set the delegate to 'self'. And make MapsViewController handle the delegate method.

```
- (void)universitiesViewController:(UniversitiesViewController *)uvc selectedIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to see if any of the storyboard methods would make it easier.  Guess not.